# How do you use the results from voice recognition in Android?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

So I have ran the sample app here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

I can't, however, figure out how to use the results. I have tried a couple of different simple things but haven't had any results. I have also been looking around on the web and there is nothing useful.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very well documented [here](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/). I doubt if I can explain it any better than this.

Comment: I've read over that tutorial, which pretty much matches the exact code I've linked to. It shows the possible matches from the voice recognition. However, it doesn't explain how you could use the results. What if I wanted an app to respond with "Hi" if I said "Hello"?

Comment: So then that should be your question, please update it. I'll try to look around. I don't have the answer for this question right away.